# Mixed effects model for repeated measures approach in R

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, reporting, pseudo-r-squared

I'm using mixed effects models for repeated measures (MMRM) in R with the `nlme` package for the first time as part of a research project and have read lots of posts here to learn about the intricacies of these models. I am hoping to verify that I'm using the right approach — and ask a couple of questions that I haven't seen on here. Your feedback and insights would be much appreciated!

The data is from a trial with repeated measures on a survey that was measured from Baseline to Week 12 at uneven time points. The intervention was given at Day 0. The timepoints of interest for the study outcome are Week 1, Week 3, and Week 12. It's a small dataset (n < 20) and it has missing values for individuals that dropped out of the study at different timepoints (Week 1, Week 6, Week 9) or who randomly missed a week.

I've created some mock data that reflects the shape and roughly the values of the data:

| ID | time | category | gender | score | change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | bl00 | 0 | 1 | 33 | 0 |
| P1 | wk01 | 0 | 1 | 29 | -4 |
| P1 | wk03 | 0 | 1 | 23 | -10 |
| P1 | wk12 | 0 | 1 | 24 | -9 |
| P2 | bl00 | 1 | 0 | 40 | 0 |
| P2 | wk01 | 1 | 0 | 20 | -20 |
| P2 | wk03 | 1 | 0 | 25 | -15 |
| P2 | wk12 | 1 | 0 | 25 | -15 |
| P3 | bl00 | 0 | 0 | 60 | 0 |
| P3 | wk01 | 0 | 0 | 21 | -39 |
| P3 | wk03 | 0 | 0 | NA | NA |
| P3 | wk12 | 0 | 0 | NA | NA |

`ID` is the participant ID, `time` is the time point of the measurement (bl00 = baseline, wk01 = Week 1, etc), `category` is a binary categorical variable, `gender` is binary of M/F, `score` is the score for that time point, and `change` is the change in score from baseline to that time point. I'm treating ID, time, category, and gender as factors.

A couple of questions:

#### Question 1.

I plotted the mean change over the four timepoints and found that it is not totally linear. It drops down dramatically to week 1 and then increases a bit towards week 12. So I transformed the visit to days (bl00 = 0, wk01 = 7, etc) and added it as a quadratic effect for time using splines. Then I tested model performance based on `AIC` and `BIC`:

```
data$days_ns <- ns(data$days, 3, intercept=FALSE)

null <- nlme::lme(
  score ~ 1, random = ~1|ID, 
  data, 
  na.action=na.exclude, method="ML"
)

linear <- nlme::lme(
  score ~ time, random = ~1|ID, 
  data, na.action=na.exclude, method="ML"
)

quad <- lme(
  score ~ days_ns, 
  random = list(ID = pdDiag(~ days_ns)), data, 
  na.action=na.exclude, method="ML"
)
```

Each model was a significant (p < 0.001) improvement from the previous one:

| Model | df | AIC | BIC | logLik |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | 1 | 6 | 336.8193 | 348.0465 |
| linear | 2 | 6 | 279.7095 | 290.9367 |
| quad | 3 | 9 | 264.3566 | 281.1974 |

But with the quad model the interpretability goes out the window since the mean inferred change in the summary table is no longer related to the different timepoints. Does it make sense to go with the slightly worse performing linear model in favor of interpretability of the model output? Also, is there something wrong in my approach to the models themselves?

#### Question 2.

Given that nothing is glaringly wrong here (fingers crossed)... When it comes to describing and interpreting the output of the model using the linear MMRM model:

Ultimately, I used the model:

`linear <- lme(score ~ time + category + gender, random = ~1|ID, data, method="REML", na.action=na.exclude)`

- Does this look correct? And is it right to say: "participant ID was added as a random effect, which allows for varying intercepts and slopes for each participant"?
- I ran an anova on the model output using `aov <- anova(linear.model)`. Is it appropriate to say, "There was a large, statistically significant effect of time on scores using the MRMM model (*F*(3, 32) = 32.35 , *p* <.0001)" and in describing the approach: "The P value associated with the time effect in the MMRM model obtained through type II analysis was used to assess the overall change in scores"?
- Lastly, based on [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7240/proportion-of-explained-variance-in-a-mixed-effects-model) and the method developed by [Nakagawa & Schielzeth](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00261.x/abstract) (2013), I used the `r.squaredGLMM(x)` function to calculate Pseudo-R-squared values for the `fixed` and `fixed + random` effects of the MMRM model. According the result, 83% of the variance can be explained by `fixed + random` effects, and 60% is explained by `fixed` effects alone. Does this reflect a lot of variance for each participant? If the amount of variance explained by `fixed` vs. `fixed + random` were the same, does it mean that the random effects should not be included and a different model should be used?

Comment: A few small points: I would expect a MMRM to contain time as categorical, sidestepping the linearity issues (not saying that is necessarily better - just that the term is quite specific in some fields). Your final model also does not contain a random slope, only an intercept. Not sure where you get the 'type III' from, this is not what happens in a default `anova` call. Did all subjects get the same intervention, because otherwise I would expect its effect to be estimated from an interaction with time?

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, @PBulls! Yes, all subjects received the same intervention and there was no control group. Sorry, yes, I was playing around with different settings for the `anova` it should say "type II" (I'll edit).

Would you recommend adding a random slope? There are quite large variations (some participants' scores decrease drastically and stay low, while others decrease drastically and then go back up to near baseline). I tried adding `time|subject_id` to my model, but it didn't converge — so that would lead me to believe it's become too complex/overparameterized, or?

Comment: As well as what @PBulls said,I would plot the predicted values (along with CIs?) and see how different the results are between the three. If the results look substantively similar, I wouldn't worry (much).

Comment: From all you've said, including keeping time continuous, I would indeed include random slopes. The only always correct answer is going to be 'it depends', but the rule of thumb I've been taught is that it's better to have a random effect that *may* exist rather than not have one that *does* exist. Obviously you pay a price in computational complexity and residual df. Have you considered fitting time as factor, or do you really need to fit a linear slope? From the sound of it that doesn't seem to be a very realistic assumption, and you'd still be able to make inference on 'change at W12' etc.

Comment: Random slope and intercept models are unlikely to fit the serial correlation patterns observed in studies of this type.  It is often better to model the correlation pattern directly and to not use random effects, as discussed [here](https://fharrell.com/post/re).